# phpmailer issue - smtp.office365.co.uk connection failed

Tags: smtp, office365, phpmailer, smtp-auth

I a, having issues with my phpmailer establishing a connection to office365

Can anybody help me debug this?

Thanks

```
2020-04-30 16:07:03 Connection: opening to ssl://smtp.office365.com:587, timeout=30, options=array ( )
2020-04-30 16:07:03 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number [/home/useraccount/public_html/hr/application/third_party/phpmailer/class.smtp.php line 293]
2020-04-30 16:07:03 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto [/home/useraccount/public_html/hr/application/third_party/phpmailer/class.smtp.php line 293]
2020-04-30 16:07:03 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.office365.com:587 (Unknown error) [/home/useraccount/public_html/hr/application/third_party/phpmailer/class.smtp.php line 293]
2020-04-30 16:07:03 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0)
2020-04-30 16:07:03 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are using an old version of PHPMailer, so [get the latest version](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

You have a TLS error because you're using `ssl` mode on a port expecting `tls` encryption mode, so change your code to this:

```
$mail->Host = 'smtp.office365.com';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 587;
```

Read the docs the error message points you at, since [this exact problem](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#using-encryption) is covered in detail.